# Seek in flowplayer on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I want to seek a flowplayer at the page load.

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $f(0).seek(5);
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  while(!$f(0).isLoaded()) {
    $f(0).seek(5);
  }
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $f(0).onLoad(function() {
    $f(0).seek(5);
  });
});
```

and this one gave result, for a while

```
$f(0).onLoad(function() {
  $f(0).seek(5);
});
```

The last one moved the pointer to 5 seconds, and back to the start right after.
I want it to stand there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it!

Used

```
$f(0).onLoad(function() {
    $f(0).seek(5);
    setTimeout('$f(0).seek(5)',1000);
}
```

Then it seeked to 5, jumped back to zero for some reason, and seeked to 5 again.

Comment: Was this after or in your config? also what is 0 your id of the player container?

Answer (score 2):

official answer:
http://flowplayer.org/forum/3/101287#post-101528

---

*looks like I was downvoted for just putting a link, and that is understandable as flowplayer has changed their forum URLS!*

https://web.archive.org/web/20120629142246/http://flowplayer.org/forum/3/101287

*Here is the OP*

```
Found this old question on stack overflow...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034858/seek-in-flowplayer-on-page-load 

Wondering what the official answer is? How do you seek on load?
```

*and the response*

```
The onLoad event (of the player) is to early an event to seek a clip. 
So you cannot seek onLoad.

You can seek once a clip is loaded and in play or pause state. 
Move the seek in the onStart event of the clip - always assuming that you deploy via a streaming server.
```

Comment: Thanks for updating that. I found that you can also provide a starting time in the clip via the URL (not sure how cross-browser compatible this one is though) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range

Answer (score 0):

I think in some cases it would help to pause the player, jump to the prefered position and the start again. When you have Flowplayer configured to auto buffer it will start playing and pause at the first frame. That could maybe explain the behavior you are seeing (seek to 5, jump to 0 and jump to 5 again. But I think your fix using the load event pretty well solves it, I've used a similar trick to wait for duration to become available.